# How to set primary key constraint name, generated by hibernate on a table with a composite key?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to set the primary key constraint name as `MyEmbeddable_PK`, which is dynamically generated as `PK__MyEmb__ED24807C4DAE15BD` from hibernate.
How to override that created primary key constraint so that `MyEmbeddable_PK` could be generated from hibernate instead of the dynamically created one ?

My entity is as below

```
@Entity
public class MyBaseEntity {

   @EmbeddedId
   private MyEmbeddable id;

   // other...
}
```

Comment: I would expect it to work similarly to any other `@Id`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32160370/2342957

Comment: I think you have identified the question incorrectly. What i want is to define a `composite primary key`, where as in the solution you mentioned it only has a `primary key` also the suggested solution is not working for my case. Anyways Thank you.

Comment: But you can also add multiple columns in the index definition, so an index for a composite id should also be doable.
But maybe I really did not fully understand your intent.

Comment: @thelonius This is regarding the question duplication you said.
If it is similar it would have been something like this.
```sql
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT(
    ID       INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    USERNAME VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    EMAIL    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblAccount_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID, USERNAME)
)
```

Comment: but my problem is something like this,
```sql
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT(
    USERNAME VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    EMAIL    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tblAccount_ID PRIMARY KEY (USERNAME, EMAIL)
)
```
So [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160370/hibernate-constraint-name)  is not similar to mine.

Comment: Well, according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/25832552/2342957 it's not possible to rename the primary key index, as it is created by Oracle, before Hibernate will create its indexes. Which underlying database are you using?